# FFMPEG wmv conversion to flv

Tags: ffmpeg, sample-rate

anyone using ffmpeg

I have a fairly simple wmv exported by a user from movie maker with standard output and want to convert to .flv using

C:>ffmpeg -i "E:\Jab Core 4 Recounters.wmv" -vcodec flv "C:\Net Projects\SVN\IntegratedAlgorithmics\src\MediaAdmin\MediaAdmin\bin\Debug\Movies\Jab Core 4 Recounters.flv" -ar 44100

the output / error i receive is

```
FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilt
er --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-pthreads --enable-avisynth --enable-libfaac -
-enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enabl
e-libvorbis --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar 16 2009 16:09:18, gcc: 4.2.4 [Sherpya]
[wmv3 @ 0x1c0d490]Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000
/1) -> 30.00 (30/1)
Input #0, asf, from 'E:\Jab Core 4 Recounters.wmv':
  Duration: 00:01:55.99, start: 5.000000, bitrate: 813 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3, yuv420p, 640x480, 586 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc

Output #0, flv, to 'C:\Net Projects\SVN\IntegratedAlgorithmics\src\MediaAdmin\Me
diaAdmin\bin\Debug\Movies\Jab Core 4 Recounters.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc

    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
[wmv3 @ 0x1c0d490]Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
[libmp3lame @ 0x1c0d8d0]flv does not support that sample rate, choose from (4410
0, 22050, 11025).
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
```

i added th -ar switch when i got the error the first time

the codec info i have on the file is as follows

```
General
Complete name                    : E:\Jab Core 4 Recounters.wmv
Format                           : Windows Media
File size                        : 11.3 MiB
Duration                         : 2mn 0s
Overall bit rate mode            : Variable
Overall bit rate                 : 780 Kbps
Maximum Overall bit rate         : 949 Kbps
Encoded date                     : UTC 2009-03-07 07:02:41.121
Writing application              :  6.0.6000.16386 / Windows Movie Maker
Application                      : Windows Movie Maker 6.0.6000.16386

Video
ID                               : 2
Format                           : VC-1
Format profile                   : MP@ML
Codec ID                         : WMV3
Codec ID/Info                    : Windows Media Video 9
Codec ID/Hint                    : WMV3
Duration                         : 2mn 0s
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 587 Kbps
Width                            : 640 pixels
Height                           : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 4/3
Frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Resolution                       : 24 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.064
Stream size                      : 8.46 MiB (75%)
Language                         : en-us

Audio
ID                               : 1
Format                           : WMA2
Format profile                   : L3
Codec ID                         : 161
Codec ID/Info                    : Windows Media Audio 2
Description of the codec         : Windows Media Audio 9.2 - VBR Quality 90, 48 kHz, stereo 1-pass VBR
Duration                         : 2mn 0s
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 186 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
Resolution                       : 16 bits
Stream size                      : 2.68 MiB (24%)
Language                         : en-us
```

i see alot of people with this issue with so solution or cause

any ideas would be helpful
thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your question.  New lines and quote/code formatting where appropriate

Comment: thank you, hope thats better, the cmd line output is still a lil messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what little help it may be, you can see that the source audio is at 48khz, and flv is refusing it. ffmpeg is apparently ignoring your -ar flag. Your first step needs to be to resample the audio... you could try transcoding to some intermediary format to get the sample rate converted, and then transcode from there to flv.

Comment: any ideas what i could convert to get it it to flv eventually all within ffmpeg

Comment: Conceivably you could have two ffmpeg calls, input->temp, temp->flv.
I imagine it's going to be a process of experimentation to find a good intermediary.

My personal preference would be to strip the video out to one temp file (MOV/AVI?), and strip the audio to another (WAV?). Then manually resample the audio, and merge the two into your output FLV.

Answer (score 10):

In ffmpeg, options must prefix the input file they relate to. Move `-ar 44100` to the front and it will work.

Comment: Hi - I am having similar issues with wmv files - have you tried this? Does it work?

Comment: @undefined yes, I stumbled over the same problem with a wmv file, found this stackoverflow question, solved it, and wrote it here a couple of days later

Answer (score 3):

I know question already has an answer but I thought it might help someone.
If you are facing the audio sample rate issue please use the following command

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 video.flv`

```
-i input file name
-ar audio sampling rate in Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

More precisely: in ffmpeg, options must prefix the **output** file they relate to.
 Move `-ar 44100` to the front **of the output filename** and it will work.