# Python video converter packages

Tags: python, linux

Any Packages out there on python which takes a input of a particular video format and convert it to another format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyFFmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/). It's a wrapper around FFmpeg.

Or use `subprocess` and call your favourite video format conversion program.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> command = ['ffmpeg']
>>> subprocess.call(command)
```

To call `ffmpeg` with your own command which includes the details required, just extend the `command` list.

Comment: Can u give a example using subprocess

Comment: Thanks but how do u convert the file from wmv to flv .Where is that actual code

Comment: Also r u saying that its nothing but subprocess is like a os.system command.

Comment: I don't know that, however have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094157/ffmpeg-wmv-conversion-to-flv

Comment: Rajeev, yes exactly. subprocess is the newer and better way of doing `os.system`. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks that post link was useful

Comment: @Rajeev: Here's the example from the link provided by @sukhbir: `subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", input_filename, ", "-vcodec", "flv", "-ar", "44100", output_filename])`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: What is the difference between `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_call`? The docs don't say much.

Comment: @sukhbir: `.call` doesn't raise `CalledProcessError` on non-zero exit codes http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

Comment: Yes, I got it after posting, thank you. So check_call raises the exception while call just returns the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://pymedia.org/features.html
However, it's also possible to simply control the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) / [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) programs using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module, that's how I did it

Comment: Can u give a example using subprocess